# MATLAB Using fzero - returns error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use the MATLAB function `fzero` properly but my program keeps returning an error message. This is my code (made up of two m-files):

## friction_zero.m

```
function fric_zero = friction_zero(reynolds)
    fric_zero = 0.25*power(log10(5.74/(power(reynolds,0.9))),-2);
```

## flow.m

```
function f = flow(fric)
    f = 1/(sqrt(fric))-1.873*log10(reynolds*sqrt(fric))-233/((reynolds*sqrt(fric))^0.9)-0.2361;
    f_initial = friction_zero(power(10,4));
    z = fzero(@flow,f_initial)
```

The goal is to return `z` as the root for the equation specified by `f` when `flow.m` is run.

I believe I have the correct syntax as I have spent a couple of hours online looking at examples. What happens is that it returns the following error message:

> "Undefined function or variable 'fric'."

(Of course it's undefined, it's the variable I'm trying to solve!)

Can someone point out to me what I've done wrong? Thanks

## EDIT

Thanks to all who helped! You have assisted me to eventually figure out my problem.
I had to add another file. Here is a full summary of the completed code with output.

## friction_zero.m

`function fric_zero = friction_zero(re)`

`fric_zero = 0.25*power(log10(5.74/(power(re,0.9))),-2); %starting value for fric`

## flow.m

`function z = flow(fric)`

`re = power(10,4);`

`z = 1/(sqrt(fric))-1.873*log10(re*sqrt(fric))-233/((re*sqrt(fric))^0.9)-0.2361;`

## flow2.m

`f_initial = friction_zero(re); %arbitrary starting value (Reynolds)`

`x = @flow;`

`fric_root = fzero(x,f_initial)`

This returns an output of:

`fric_root = 0.0235`

Which seems to be the correct answer (phew!)

I realised that (1) I didn't define `reynolds` (which is now just `re`) in the right place, and (2) I was trying to do too much and thus skipped out on the line `x = @flow;`, for some reason when I added the extra line in, MATLAB stopped complaining. Not sure why it wouldn't have just taken `@flow` straight into `fzero()`.

Once again, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `f` is a function in your code.  This is simply an expression with `reynolds` being a constant when it isn't defined.  As such, wrap this as an anonymous function with `fric` as the input variable.  Also, you need to make sure the output variable from your function is `z`, not `f`.  Since you're solving for `fric`, you don't need to specify this as the input variable into `flow`.  Also, you need to specify `f` as the input into `fzero`, not `flow`.  `flow` is the name of your main function.  In addition, `reynolds` in `flow` is not defined, so I'm going to assume that it's the same as what you specified to `friction_zero`.  With these edits, try doing this:

```
function z = flow()
    reynolds = power(10,4);
    f = @(fric) 1/(sqrt(fric))-1.873*log10(reynolds*sqrt(fric))-233/((reynolds*sqrt(fric))^0.9)-0.2361;
    f_initial = friction_zero(reynolds);
    z = fzero(@f, f_initial); %// You're solving for `f`, not flow.  flow is your function name
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have a problem is because `flow` is called without argument I think. You should read a little more about [matlab functions](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/function.html). By the way, reynolds is not defined either.

I am afraid I cannot help you completely since I have not been doing fluid mechanics. However, I can tell you about functions.

A matlab function definition looks something like this:

```
function x0 = f(xGuess)
    a = 2;
    fcn =@(t) a*t.^3+t; % t must not be an input to f.
    disp(fcn);
    a = 3;
    disp(fcn);
    x0 = fsolve(fcn1,xGuess); % x0 is calculated here
```

The function can then ne called as `myX0 = f(myGuess)`. When you define a matlab function with arguments and return values, you must tell matlab what to do with them. Matlab cannot guess that. In this function you tell matlab to use `xGuess` as an initial guess to `fsolve`, when solving the **anonymous function** `fcn`. Notice also that matlab does not assume that an undefined variable is an independent variable. You need to tell matlab that now I want to create an anonymous function `fcn` which have an independent variable `t`.

Observation 1: I use `.^`. This is since the function will take an argument an evaluate it and this argument can also be a vector. In this particulat case I want pointwise evaluation. This is not really necessary when using `fsolve` but it is good practice if `f` is not a matrix equation, since "vectorization" is often used in matlab.

Observation 2: notice that even if `a` changes its value the function does not change. This is since matlab passes the value of a variable when defining a function and not the variable itself. A c programmer would say that a variable is passed by its value and not by a pointer. This means that `fcn` is really defined as `fcn = @(x) 2*t.^3+t;`. Using the variable `a` is just a conveniance (constants can may also be complicated to find, but when found they are just a value).

Armed with this knowledge, you should be able to tackle the problem in front of you. Also, the recursive call to `flow` in your function will eventuallt cause a crash. When you write a function that calls itself like this you must have a stopping criterium, something to tell the program when to stop. As it is now, flow will call ifself in the last row, like `z = fzero(@flow,f_initial)` for 500 times and then crash. Alos it is possible as well to define functions with zero inputs:

```
function plancksConstant = h()
    plancksConstant  = 6.62606957e−34;
```

Where the call `h` or `h()` will return Plancks constant.

Good luck!